# VB in Access 2000 : ado query got different result each time?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I got a form, which has 2 buttons, 1 is to set the input data file, 1 is to start a sub, the sub should make a query against the db. But the same simple query "select * from opt_in_customer_record;" return different thing! That's horrible! Why???

Here is my code, btnBrowse_Click() will pop window for user to select file, everytime I will the same file. btnGenData_Click() is the sub which got problem.

for the data file, here is the first 20 lines, Event_Plan_Code is the first column.
5BUDP;HongKong;050111;520010100000800
5BUDP;HongKong;010111;520010100100867
5BUDP;HongKong;130111;520010100182001
3BUDP;HongKong;050111;520010100244746
5BUDP;HongKong;040111;520010100282676
1BUDP;HongKong;110111;520010100310573
1BUDP;HongKong;120111;520010100310573
3BUDP;HongKong;310111;520010100361924
1BUDP;HongKong;310111;520010100392644
1BUDP;HongKong;290111;520010100406914
3BUDP;HongKong;280111;520010100429143
3BUDP;HongKong;190111;520010100440403
3BUDP;HongKong;300111;520010100482444
1BUDP;HongKong;130111;520010100523409
3BUDP;HongKong;210111;520010100576847
5BUDP;HongKong;230111;520010100583232
3BUDP;HongKong;200111;520010100637103
3BUDP;HongKong;160111;520010100639083
3BUDP;HongKong;190111;520010100666157
3BUDP;HongKong;250111;520010100774408

I made the program to stop if the first character of Event_Plan_Code is 1, just to stop the program for debugging. And each time I press the button, different result I got:

1st run:
5BUDP
5BUDP
5BUDP
3BUDP
5BUDP
1BUDP

it make sense.

2nd run:
3BUDP
1BUDP

The problem is that the query should start over again and the result should be the same! Now different result I got.

Thank you very much if you may answer my question!

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()

Dim filePath As String

filePath = LaunchCD(Me)

txtFilePath.Value = filePath
txtStatus.Value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnGenData_Click()
'On Error GoTo Error_Handling

Dim extractCdrFlag As Boolean


txtStatus.Value = ""
If IsNull(txtFilePath.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid input file location."
Else
    txtStatus.Value = ""
    txtStatus.Value = txtStatus.Value & "Deleting previous record from table Opt_In_Customer_Record..." & vbCrLf
    CurrentDb.Execute "deleteAll"
    txtStatus.Value = txtStatus.Value & "Delete successfully." & vbCrLf
    If FileExists(txtFilePath.Value) Then
            txtStatus.Value = txtStatus.Value & "Trying to import data from file..." & vbCrLf
            DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Import_Specification", "Opt_In_Customer_Record", txtFilePath.Value, False
            txtStatus.Value = txtStatus.Value & "Data imported successfully." & vbCrLf
            Testing
            txtStatus.Value = ""
    Else
            MsgBox "File does not exist. Please enter again."
    End If
End If

Exit Sub

Error_Handling:
MsgBox "Error while generating data! Please check your data setting!"
Exit Sub

End Sub


Sub Testing()
'On Error GoTo Error_Handling
   Dim conConnection As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim cmdCommand As New ADODB.Command
   Dim rstRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset

   Dim eventPlanCode As String
   Dim visitedCountry As String
   Dim startDateTxt As String
   Dim startDate As Date
   Dim endDate As Date
   Dim imsi As String
   Dim currentMonth As String
   Dim nextMonth As String
   Dim currentYear As String
   Dim nextYear As String
   Dim temp As Integer
   Dim sql As String

   'MsgBox CurrentDb.Name

   With conConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = CurrentDb.Name
    .Open
   End With

    'MsgBox conConnection.ConnectionString

   With cmdCommand
    .ActiveConnection = conConnection
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Opt_In_Customer_Record;"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
   End With

   With rstRecordSet
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open cmdCommand
   End With

   If rstRecordSet.EOF = False Then
        rstRecordSet.MoveFirst
        Do

            'Debug.Print txtStatus.Value
            eventPlanCode = rstRecordSet!Event_Plan_Code
            visitedCountry = rstRecordSet!Visited_Country
            startDateTxt = rstRecordSet!Start_Date
            imsi = rstRecordSet!imsi

            currentMonth = Mid$(startDateTxt, 3, 2) '01
            currentYear = "20" & Mid$(startDateTxt, 5, 2) '2011

            startDate = DateSerial(Val(currentYear), Val(currentMonth), Val(Mid$(startDateTxt, 1, 2)))
            endDate = startDate + Val(Mid$(eventPlanCode, 1, 1))

            MsgBox rstRecordSet!Event_Plan_Code

            If (Mid$(eventPlanCode, 1, 1) = "1") Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'MsgBox startDate & " " & endDate
            If (currentMonth = "01") Then
                nextMonth = "02"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "02") Then
                nextMonth = "03"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "03") Then
                nextMonth = "04"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "04") Then
                nextMonth = "05"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "05") Then
                nextMonth = "06"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "06") Then
                nextMonth = "07"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "07") Then
                nextMonth = "08"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "08") Then
                nextMonth = "09"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "09") Then
                nextMonth = "10"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "10") Then
                nextMonth = "11"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "11") Then
                nextMonth = "12"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "12") Then
                nextMonth = "01"
            End If

            temp = Val(currentYear)
            temp = temp + 1
            nextYear = Str(temp)

            'MsgBox currentYear & currentMonth & " " & nextYear & nextMonth

            'Exit Do
            rstRecordSet.MoveNext
        Loop Until rstRecordSet.EOF = True
   End If

   'sql = "select * from ( select * from " & "dbo.inbound_rated_all_" & currentYear & currentMonth & " A inner join Opt_In_Customer_Record B "


   conConnection.Close
   Set conConnection = Nothing
   Set cmdCommand = Nothing
   Set rstRecordSet = Nothing

   Exit Sub

Error_Handling:
MsgBox "Error during function Testing!"
Set conConnection = Nothing
Set cmdCommand = Nothing
Set rstRecordSet = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the rows in a particular order, add an ORDER BY clause to your query:

```
select * from opt_in_customer_record order by event_plan_code
```

Actually, event_plan_code isn't the right column because it contains duplicates, but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: If I didn't use "Order by", shouldn't it return the resultset from the 1st row to the last row sequantially?

Comment: I tried to "Order by event_plan_code", but it can only ensure the fisrt row return is "1BDRU", which is the smallest event_plan_code, but the IMSI of the same row, can be anyone, because there are more than 1 row which have the event_plan_code as "1BDRU", and vb don't ensure that?

Comment: If you don't use ORDER BY then the database is free to return the rows in any order. And as I said, event_plan_code is not the right column to sort by because it contains duplicates. You'll need either to choose a column that contains no duplicates (a column with a UNIQUE index) or to choose a set of columns that in aggregate are unique. Maybe something like ORDER BY col1, col2.